# Function is not defined even though it is

Tags: javascript

I am coding a taximeter which is calculating the drive-expenses through the elapsed time. By clicking a button the standing below function "startDrive" will normally executed, but when I am clicking on my button the browser or console respectively is showing an error which is including the message "Uncaught ReferenceError: startDrive is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (time.html:15:62)". I checked whether I mentioned the wrong Function in the "onclick" part in HTML but this is not the case. What I am doing wrong?

```
//global variables
let y = 3.9;
let reversal = 20;


//Main-function in which the sub-functions are be executed
function startDrive() {
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = y.toFixed(2) + "€";
    interval();
}

//Calculating drive-expenses
function calculate() {
    if(y < reversal) {
    y += 0.14375;
    }
    else if(y > reversal) {
        y += 0.103125;
    }
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = y.toFixed(2) + "€";
    
}

//Fixed time in which "calculate()" will be executed
function interval() {
    timerId = setInterval(calculate, 5000);
}

//Stopping interval
function stop() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

```
<button onclick = "startDrive()">start!</button>
<output id = "output1"></output>
```

Comment: The code doesn't show how you attach the function to the button click?

Comment: We don't have enough information to help here. Please make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Make sure you call the method not a value or property like: <button onclick="startDrive()">Click me</button> not <button onclick="startDrive">Click me</button>

Comment: @evolutionxbox I uploaded the HTML part

Comment: @yousoumar I uploaded the HTML part

Comment: @AndroFont thank you firstly. Can you explain more what you mean

Comment: how and where are you loding your js script to HTML?

Comment: Could you please share a link to your full HTML and JS via JSFiddle, CodePen, or something else so that we can properly understand the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

here

```html
<button onclick = "startDrive">start!</button>
```

use `startDrive()` instead of `startDrive`

you can watch a sample at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_onclick.asp).

Comment: In my actual code i wrote my code like your suggested. So even in this way the function "startDrive()" is not defined according to the browser

Comment: sorry , I cant replay your problem,your code runs perfectly on my side,this is my [sourcecode](https://sourceb.in/BFUd4zmBRe).

Answer (score 0):

It says `startDrive` is not defined, so it seems your function definitions are never executed.

If you put your code in a plain script tag inside head it works just fine:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-joana-ubttg5?file=/index.html

Comment: Although I agree with you, this wouldn't solve the issue because (unless the JS never ran) it would have executed by the time the OP clicked the button.

Comment: "it seems your function definitions are never executed." Why is that so

Comment: If they were, `startDrive` would be defined. So either they're never run or they're not run in the global context. You'll have to elaborate on your setup. This is just guesswork. It generally works, as you can see in the sandbox.